# Gitlab project bot commit author as an authenticated user

Tags: gitlab, renovate

I'm trying to set up a self-hosted Gitlab project with [renovate](https://docs.renovatebot.com/) to automatically create merge requests for dependency updates.

I created a Gitlab [project token/bot](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#project-bot-users) with the name "renovate" which resolves to "project_123_bot".  The rub is that my project uses [push rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html#enabling-push-rules) to "Check whether the commit author is a GitLab user".  I do not know what I should use as the git commit author for renovate-generated commits.  I've tried:

- `Renovate Bot <renovate@gitlab.myorg.com>`
- `Renovate Bot <project_123_bot>`
- `Renovate Bot <project_123_bot@gitlab.myorg.com>`

among others, and I always get this rejection when pushing:

```
remote: GitLab: Author 'project_123_bot@gitlab.myorg.com' is not a member of team
```

What is the appropriate git commit author to use for project bots?  Is it not possible for project bots to commit changes as a verified authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

The correct email seems to be `project123_bot@example.com`.  I need to look into where the `example.com` comes from.

Edit: "example.com" is hard-coded, see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/292668